# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: with double equal in selector ==

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have office 365 id on message divs. such as

```
<div id="AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0wYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA==">Message Subject</div>
```

But when I call it in functions. It gives `jquery-2.1.1.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

This **works** on devtools console.

```
$('#AQMkADFGFGDFGDFGwYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA')
```

This **does not work** on devtools console. I want to fix this because office 365 messages ids usually have double equal in the end `==`.

```
 $('#AQMkADFGFGDFGDFGwYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA==')
```

Comment: Try [escaping the character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1048572)

Comment: just a comment, if you're using the outdated HTML4, equals character is not allowed: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is **jQuery uses CSS syntax for selecting elements**.

You can use one regex expression to escape with double backslashes for an ID that has characters used in CSS notation.

```js
console.log($("#"+"AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0wYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA==".replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "\\$1" )).text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS0wYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA==">Message Subject</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

1. If the structure is not known to change, save yourself a headache and select by structure instead of ID.
2. If you must select by ID, either use an attribute selector:

   ```
   $('[id="AQMkADFGFGDFGDFGwYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA=="]')
   ```

   or [escape the equals signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825948/jquery-selectors-and-backslashes/5826146#5826146):

   ```
   $('#AQMkADFGFGDFGDFGwYWIxLTU1ADI4LTAwAi0wMAoALgAAA1IXzflHRQlLlY3LIdjzH3MBADg_s4AQY3NEqDFmBjvfdZIAAAIBDwAAAA\\=\\=')
   ```

Comment: @Cemal: I overlooked that on purpose because it's not the issue.

Comment: @BoltClock let me try this

Comment: Yes this works, thanks! I actually used Sphinx replace function since == were in middle too sometimes.